# Is it possible to add a feature from app to another through .xml editing?

Tags: keyboard, notification-bar

So I had just discovered this keyboard app called the Multiling O Keyboard which is very useful, but one thing I hate about it is that, it doesn't have the permanent notification feature which the Hacker's Keyboard has.

So is it possible to add the Hacker's Keyboard's permanent notification feature to Multiling O Keyboard?

This feature will help me open the soft keyboard even without textfield to write into like the Hacker's Keyboard.

PS. I'm not good in coding, I just want a decent keyboard for myself.

Comment: Depends on the app but typically changes to app behavior require code changes.

Comment: [Persistent notification needs code changes](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setOngoing(boolean)) though